# How to generate dynamic Laravel Nova select field?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-nova

I'm trying to create a dynamic Laravel Nova select field but am having some issues.

I have an array in my config file that I am trying to use to generate these values. Here is my code:

```
Select::make('Options')->options(function () {
    $options = config('options.options');
    $optionsArray = [];
    foreach($options as $index => $option) {
        $optionsArray[$index] = $option;
    }
    return [
        $optionsArray
    ];
}),
```

But, this does not seem to work. The `$optionsArray` is populated with all of the values that I want, but the select field has no options in Nova on the front end. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is more complex than actually necessary. Consider the following snippet, which is a generic version of your solution:

```
$input = [
    'a' => 123,
    'b' => 234,
    'c' => 'ABC'
];
$output = [];

foreach($input as $index => $option) {
    $output[$index] = $option;
}
```

Dumping `$input` and `$output` will literally yield the same result:

```
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(123)
  ["b"]=>
  int(234)
  ["c"]=>
  string(3) "ABC"
}
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(123)
  ["b"]=>
  int(234)
  ["c"]=>
  string(3) "ABC"
}
```

This means we can simply omit this step, which brings us to following intermediary solution:

```
Select::make('Options')->options(function () {
    return config('options.options');
})
```

Because the `->options($opts)` function on the `Select` object accepts an array of options as alternative to a callback function, we can simply pass `config('options.options')` to it. To ensure that the code doesn't break if the configuration is missing, we can also use `[]` as default value by passing it as second parameter:

```
Select::make('Options')->options(config('options.options', []))
```

---

If you pass a nested array to the `->options($opts)` method (or return one from the passed callback), you'll create select option groups. This is handy if you want to group the options of your select box, for example group cities by country like so:

```
Austria
  Vienna
  Bregenz
Germany
  Berlin
  Hamburg
United States
  New York
  Los Angeles
  Detroit
```

To do so, you'd need your options to be an array of the following form, where the array keys are used as internal stored values and can be changed freely:

```
[
    'vienna' => ['label' => 'Vienna', 'group' => 'Austria'],
    'bregenz' => ['label' => 'Bregenz', 'group' => 'Austria'],
    'berlin' => ['label' => 'Berlin', 'group' => 'Germany'],
    'hamburg' => ['label' => 'Hamburg', 'group' => 'Germany'],
    'new_york' => ['label' => 'New York', 'group' => 'United States'],
    'los_angeles' => ['label' => 'Los Angeles', 'group' => 'United States'],
    'detroit' => ['label' => 'Detroit', 'group' => 'United States'],
]
```

---

By using `array_filter($opts)` on the options before returning them in a callback, you will remove options being `null`. This makes only sense in a dynamic environment with dynamic options.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, the solution was to wrap the `$optionsArray` in a `array_filter` method when returning, like so:

```
return array_filter($optionsArray);
```

Comment: Your solution is more complex than necessary: `Select::make('Options')->options(config('options.options', []))`. Using `array_filter()` will only remove `null`s which you should simply omit in the config.

Comment: Great thank you! Can you make this an answer so it can be accepted?